# Ignoring numbers with letters

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
  const char *str = "11 2 3 5a";
  int i = 0;
  unsigned int count = 0, tmp = 0;

  printf("%s\n", str);

  while (sscanf(&str[count], "%d %n", &i, &tmp) != EOF) {
    if (!isdigit(str[count])) break;
    count += tmp;
    printf("number %d\n", i);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I have something like this, but this is still grabbing the `5`. How can I make it ignore numbers with letters in them? So the above `str` example should print 11 2 3 instead of `11 2 3 5a`

Comment: The format specifier `%n` would do nothing. I think you wanted to use there `%u` instead.

Comment: @RohanBari I disagree.  `"%n"` use is fine here.

Comment: zzca, Do you want to accept integers with a leading sign character `+,-`?

Comment: Given a modifiable string, e.g. `char str[] = "11 2 3 5a";`, you can split the string into tokens using `strtok`, and then check each token for non-digits before converting the token into a number.

Answer (score 1):

Read your values intially as substrings, then use `strtol` with the end-marker option to determine whether the substring just-read converts to an integer completely (i.e. that it landed on the string terminator to complete processing).

It would look something like this, more or less:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char * str = "11 2 3 5a";
    unsigned int count = 0, tmp = 0;
    
    char s[ strlen(str) + 1 ];
    
    printf("%s\n", str);
    while (sscanf(str+count, "%s%n", s, &tmp))
    {
        count += tmp;
        char *end = NULL;
        long i = strtol(s, &end, 10);
        if (end && *end)
            break;
        printf("number %ld\n", i);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
number 11
number 2
number 3
```

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Were that to be done a non-digit leading char (ex: `a`) would *pass* (since `end > s` would be false). Remember, that test is to detect failure, not success.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yeah, that's viable.

Comment: @WhozCraig I tried this but it seems like when you remove the 'a' it prints the last number twice. I should probably mention that the str will be input from the user using getline(). I just need it to print the numbers until an invalid thing was entered 
EXP 1 2 3 a 5 6 7 = 1 2 3 
and 
1 2 3a = 1 2
valid input would be
1 2 3 4 5 = 1 2 3 4 5